# Generate data with normally distributed noise and mean function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, normal-distribution

I created a numpy array with n values from 0 to 2pi. Now, I want to generate n test data points deviating from sin(x) normally distributed.

So i figured I need to do something like this: `t = sin(x) + noise`. Where the noise must be something like this: `noise = np.random.randn(mean, std)`.

However, I do not know how I can calculate the noise when my mean is sin(x) (and not a constant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to [`numpy.random.randn`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html) are not the mean and standard deviation.  For that, you want [`numpy.random.normal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html).  Its signature is

```
normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None)
```

To add noise to your sin function, simply use a mean of 0 in the call of `normal()`.  The mean corresponds to the `loc` argument (i.e. "location"), which by default is 0.  So, given that `x` is something like `np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n)`, you can do this:

```
t = np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(scale=std, size=n)
```

---

You *could* use `numpy.random.randn`, but you have to scale it by `std`, because `randn` returns samples from the standard normal distribution, with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.  To use `randn`, you would write:

```
t = np.sin(x) + std * np.random.randn(n)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you add the noise to the `y` coordinate, some of the test data points may have values outside the normal range of the sine function, that is, not from -1 to 1, but from -(1+noise) to +(1+noise). I suggest to add the noise to the `x` coordinate:

```
t = np.sin(x + np.random.uniform(-noise, noise, x.shape))
```

where `noise` must be a suitable value to your problem.